# Weblogic (12.2.1.3) - Error al Desplegar un war. "cvc-enumeration-valid"

Tags: java, java-ee, weblogic, war

Tengo un problema en mi servidor weblogic 12c, el caso es que he ido a desplegar un servicio en formato war y el servidor me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
<8:3> problem: cvc-enumeration-valid: string value '3.1' is not a valid enumeration value for web-app-versionType in namespace
```

El caso es que no tengo acceso al proyecto original, pero a mi compañera de equipo si le despliega sin problemas usando la misma version de weblogic, configurada igual.

He buscado por la red y la mayoría habla de que es causado por intentar usar una version superior de servlet sobre un weblogic antiguo, pero este no es el caso, tengo la version 12.2.1.3 que es compatible con servlets 3.1.

¿Alguna idea de que puede ser la causa de este error o como puedo arreglarlo?

PD: Como apunte, esto arrancando el WL via Eclipse en vez de forma manual, para poder tener a mano la consola. ¿Puede estar influyendo en como trabaja el servidor con los despliegues?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba actualizando el encabezado de tu web.xml, así lo pude resolver yo...

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
    </web-app>
```

[Usé esta liga de ejemplo](https://www.mkyong.com/web-development/the-web-xml-deployment-descriptor-examples/)

Comment: No, si eso es lo que dicen en todas partes. pero como dije, no tengo el proyecto original, solo tengo el war y al intentar importarlo saltan mil errores.